# Meaning of "point" in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, idioms

I can't understand what "point" means in this sentence!

The complete sentence is

> - Hookers at Quahog Point: An HBO Documentary...*

I found that on a Family Guy episode.

Thanks

EDIT: I wrote another sentence that seems easier to me to understand what "point" means

Comment: "At the point of no return", perhaps?

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us where you found this complete sentence. Given that there is a capital P in _Point_, it might simply be referring to a certain location, such as a district of a coastal city. Moreover, that doesn't even look like a complete sentence; it looks like a fragment.

Comment: It's a joke. *Quahog* (a regional term for hard-shell clams) is the fictional Rhode Island town where Family Guy is set, and *Quahog Point* has the form of a local geographical name--presumably the 'point' or peninsula on which Quahog lies. The joke is a reference to a 2002 HBO documentary on street prostitution in Hunts Point, a neighborhood in the Bronx borough of New York City, which was titled "Hookers at the Point".

Comment: Thanks to both of you! So point is what you mean for "Peninsula" more or less?

Answer (score 1):

**[Point](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/point)**  (definition 6)

> a projecting usually tapering piece of land or a sharp prominence

Answer (score -1):

In a geographical context, the meaning of "point" to me is literally suggesting a point on a map. I don't know whether this is actually what it is supposed to mean, but as a native English speaker it has served me well so far.

Comment: Whatever Point is a common geographic name in English.  "Stevens Point" is a city in Wisconsin, "Point State Park" is a park in Pittsburgh covering the *point* of land where 2 rivers merge, etc.